# Video element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

there is an option in html to preload images.
I can do this:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "someName.jpg";
```

and than the image will be loaded with the page, and if I want the image to be used later in my script, I won't have to wait until it was loaded.

However, the video has a different structure.
Is it possible to preload it just like the images?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think that preloading video is a good idea since it is possible the user will never even watch it and you would be forcing the bandwidth on them.

HTML5  introduces preload="auto" which may be what you're looking for (although I don't believe it is supported in all browsers). See the link below:

[HTML video Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: According to MDN's [`<video>` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/video), `autoplay` is supported in Firefox, Chrome, Opera 10, and IE 9 and later. It is supported in desktop Safari but *not* in mobile Safari (deliberately, due to bandwidth concerns). (Also: I would personally suggest you investigate alternatives to W3Schools, which has been subject to some [significant criticism](http://w3fools.com/).)

Comment: For "which browsers support feature X" I'd go with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/video) for narrow features (specific property fields) or [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) for major features.

Comment: The W3C spec is great for pointing out what features *should* exist or how things are supposed to work, but not necessary what features are actually implemented in browsers.